# Airflow DAG - schedule at different times based on the environment either dev or prod

Tags: airflow

I want to schedule DAG at different times based on the environment either dev or prod.
I want the dev dag to run every 10 minutes and prod dag to run every hour. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't you have a variable defining environment inside the DAG? If not you should have it and easily make the schedule interval conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally set schedule's value based on any parameter which defines if the environment is dev or prod in python file.

Example

```
schedule= '0 0 * * 1' if env=='prod'  else '0 0 * * 5'
```

Just define variable 'env' whose value must be passed either from env.yaml or should be passed at runtime when triggering the dag